# Abstract domain monad

Tags: pl.programming-languages, ct.category-theory, semantics, program-verification, program-analysis

I was reading [old lecture from a CS course at Cornel](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6110/2013sp/lectures/lec36-sp13.pdf) and I have some doubts about the following at 2.4
It defines how to transform domains between each other via a Galois Insertion, more formally:

Suppose we have an abstract interpretation for $M$ , with corresponding monadic operations $[·]$ and $(·)*∗$, and a Galois insertion $(\alpha, \gamma)$ from $M$ to $A$. Then we can define a coarser abstract interpretation for $A$ via monadic operations $[·]′$
and $(·)^∗′$

$[·]′ = α \circ [·]$

$(f )^∗′ = α \circ f^∗ \circ γ$

Proving the second monad law is easy:
$bind id = \alpha \circ id \circ \gamma
        = \alpha \circ \gamma =_{\text{by GI}} id$

But for the first for example I don't see how it can be true:
$f = bind f \circ unit = (\alpha \circ f \circ \gamma) \circ \alpha$

Bonus question: in the note there isn't any reference on this topic where I can find more information about this?

Comment: That section of the notes has some pretty major errors in it, which you can notice just by looking at the types. And, tbh, it seems pointless to try to compose abstract interpretations (compose nicely already) by first turning them into monads (don't compose nicely).